# Hook-content polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $\lambda$ denote the hook of size $d$ for a fixed integer $d>0$. For $d=2$ there are two kinds of hooks for $d=3$ there are 3 different kind and so on. $c(\Box)$ denote the content of the $\lambda$.

I want to know if following results appear in literature if anyone can give me a reference or proof 
$$ \sum_{\lambda\in \text{different hook of size d}} \frac{1}{|\lambda|!} (-1)^{ht(\lambda)-1}  \, \dim \lambda \, \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} \frac{1}{1-c(\Box)h}$$
that the above equation equal to 
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2d-2)!}{ (d-1)!}h^{d-1}\prod_{i=1}^{d-1} \frac{1}{(1+ih)(1-ih)}
\end{equation}

Comment: The hooks of size $d$ are indexed by the integers $1, 2, \ldots, d$, where integer $i$ corresponds to the hook whose first row has length $i$. This latter hook has height $d-i+1$ and dimension $\dbinom{d-1}{i-1}$. The contents of its cells are $i-d, i-d+1, \ldots, i-1$. So the thing boils down to an identity for binomial coefficients.

Comment: Okay. So after some rewriting and cancellation, your equality becomes $\sum\limits_{i=1}^d \left(-1\right)^{d-i} \dbinom{d-1}{i-1} \prod\limits_{u=1}^d \dfrac{1}{1-h\left(i-u\right)} = d \left(2d-2\right)! \prod\limits_{i=1}^{d-1} \dfrac{h^{d-1}}{\left(1+ih\right)\left(1-ih\right)}$. That said, I suspect the right hand side has too many $h$s.

Comment: I put the equation in maple and checked it $h$'s power are all good. The combinatorial coefficient is $\frac{(2d-2)!}{(d-1)!}$

Comment: Also I just updated the sign issue.

Comment: The $h$-power cannot be right. If you multiply your equality through by $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{d-1}\left(\left(1+ih\right)\left(1-ih\right)\right)$, then the left hand side becomes a polynomial in $h$ of degree $\leq d-1$, whereas the right hand side becomes $d \left(2d-2\right)! h^{\left(d-1\right)^2}$. Maybe you want to move that product sign into the denominator.

Comment: Actually, this might be an important step towards solving the problem. Multiply through by $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{d-1}\left(\left(1+ih\right)\left(1-ih\right)\right)$. Once corrected, the equality becomes a polynomial identity of degree $\leq d-1$, so you just need to check it on $d$ distinct values of $h$. You can get creative there; with the right choices you might get some very basic binomial identities.

Comment: No, it doesn't RHS then would be just $\frac{(2d-2)!}{(d-1)!}h^{d-1}$. Your combinatorial coefficient is not right.

Comment: There is a product of $d-1$ factors, each of which contributes a $h^{d-1}$.

Comment: yes there is how do you prove that ?

Comment: After multiplying with $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{d-1}\left(\left(1+ih\right)\left(1-ih\right)\right)$ on the LHS is there any way to write each of the $d$ monomials. I think I am messing up there.

Comment: The $h^{d-1}$ on the right-hand side should be outside the product, not inside.

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: You can prove the identity by checking that both sides have the same poles, that these poles are simple, and that they have the same residues. There should be a nicer proof.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked and proved they have the same pole on both sides.  Poles are simple I am trying to show the residue are same for each pole.